# Import courses from moodle to drupal

Tags: drupal, moodle

How can i import the courses from moodle to drupal in  a particular region. I have created a view but doesn't find how to import various courses from moodle directly

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the help of moodle_views module . we have to make a block of that module  and just assigned it in particular region.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the person who developed the moodle_views module, specifically so Moodle courses could be displayed using Views in Drupal. Feel free to contact me, or submit an issue at https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/moodle_views if you have any questions or problems or feature requests.